# How do I set up my Panlong PL-G300 Mini PS2 to HDMI Video Converter?

Tags: ps2

Recently, I bought a Panlong PL-G300 Mini PS2 to HDMI Video Converter. I set it up with my SCPH-30001 PS2 model using the USB cable to plug into my PS2 for power. For my HDMI cable, I used Amazon's Basic ones. Whenever I unplug the USB cable for the power, my TV turns on but there is no visuals. When I plug it back in, it goes to standby mode. My PlayStation 2 is working as it can turn on and off and eject the disc. My PS2 to HDMI's text on the box will not turn on for some reason. Any suggestions?

Amazon Link: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00D875R5K/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D875R5K)

Comment: Does your TV actually support 408p via HDMI?

Comment: Why are you unplugging the power and expecting visuals?

Comment: @Thebluefish That might be it...

Comment: Also I found this from the amazon reviews: ```Warnings: be sure to have your PS2 set up to play Component video and not Composite before hooking up the adapter or you'll be working blind. This is in the system config when you boot the console up with no disc.```